# Difference between mc184Z/B and mc184Z/A keyboard

Tags: keyboard, wifi

I recently bought an mc184Z/A keyboard but a mc184Z/B was shipped to me. Was I cheated? Or only the name changed? any way I wanted to buy a US type wireless keyboard and I got one with an international layout... :(

Comment: See differences in Apple's [doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2841)

Comment: The page isnt specifying the type of keyboard by its code like mc....z/a

Comment: It tells you a US vs International English

Comment: And how do I get their codes? I want to check them by code in order to verify if I was cheated or not

Comment: The answer to that biy is if you ordered X and then got Y then the supplier did not supply the correct keyboard.

Comment: The suplier told me that mc184z/b is the new mame of mc184z/a... That is what I want to verify.

Comment: Anyway the image showing the keyboard was looking like Us layout

Answer (score 1):

If you search for MC184Z on the US store, neither part number you listed is shown. The closest match is a Dutch layout wireless keyboard.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184N/B/apple-wireless-keyboard

It's hard to know what you bought with the details you provided, but if you can link to a store listing showing the specifications, it might help us help you (or by that point, you may have your answer since the Apple pages for each item usually list the specifications for each).

If however you simply want a US wireless keyboard, here is the part number:

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184LL/B/apple-wireless-keyboard-english

Comment: This is the shop were i bought from:  http://store.apcom.ro/applewirelesskeyboard-p-81.html. The image shows a Us layouted keyboard but in reality it isn't... i think that is one ethical drawback the shop shouldn't permit to itself.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a legitimate complaint with the seller. In their defense, you did select them and there is some level of responsibility to make sure you know what you are getting (in terms of after-sales support, warranty, exchange policy when selecting a vendor) and it's hard to blame them if you don't like their policies after you've sent them your money. Luckily the details of the transaction aren't really important for the site, so let's leave the specifics in comments since no one else is likely to order this part from that vendor but the general knowledge is good to have here.